# Is there something like a jubilee clip (hose clamp) that is extra long?

Tags: wood, outdoor

One side of my raised flower bed has come away and I'd like to tie something around it, a bit like a belt, something more secure and weatherproof than rope.

Comment: And I learned that "jubilee clip" is another term for what we know as "hose clamp" in the US.

Answer (score 1):

You can open hose clamps completely and chain them together. They're readily available in 6" diameters and perhaps larger.

You could also purchase a ratchet strap for about the same cost. It would let you avoid having screw buckles showing at intervals.

Or you can use about any chain or strap you like along with a turnbuckle.

Comment: It looks like the ratchet strap is just what I want - thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how our site works.